# How to write a doobie transaction when there's an IO stuck in the middle

Tags: scala, scala-cats, doobie, cats-effect

I want to write a basic doobie read/write transaction, however the kicker is that there is an `IO` returning call in the middle. I want to do something like this:

```
abstract class MyDAO {

  def readSomething(id: String): ConnectionIO[Option[Something]]

  def writeSomething(something: Something): ConnectionIO[Unit]

}

class MyService {

  def getNewSomething: IO[Something] = ???

}

class MyProgram(myDAO: MyDAO, myService: MyService, xa: DataSourceTransactor[IO]) {

  val transaction = myDAO.readSomething("xyz").flatMap {
    case Some(thing) => IO.pure(thing).pure[ConnectionIO] //ConnectionIO[IO[Something]]
    case None => myService.getNewSomething.map { newSomething =>
      myDAO.writeSomething(newSomething).map(_ => newSomething)
    }.sequence[ConnectionIO, Something] //can't sequence an IO! So I'm stuck with IO[ConnectionIO[Something]]
  }

  transaction.transact(xa)

}
```

But I can't sequence on the `IO`. Therefore, in the second case, I'd be stuck with `IO[ConnectionIO[Something]]` which means my transaction would end up like `ConnectionIO[IO[ConnectionIO[Something]]`.

What I want is a `ConnectionIO[IO[Something]]` that I can then run in a single transaction yielding `IO[IO[Something]]` which I can then easily flatten. (I don't want to run the `IO`.) Make sense? Any idea if this is possible to pull off?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Doobie - lifting arbitrary effect into ConnectionIO CE3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71212284/doobie-lifting-arbitrary-effect-into-connectionio-ce3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could in theory use the `LiftIO` typeclass provided by `cats-effect` and implemented by doobie like this:

```
import cats.effect._
import doobie._
import doobie.implicits._

def read: ConnectionIO[Int] = ???
def write(s: String): ConnectionIO[Unit] = ???
def transform(i: Int): IO[String] = ???

val transaction: ConnectionIO[Unit] = for {
  i <- read
  s <- transform(i).to[ConnectionIO]
  _ <- write(s)
} yield ()

transaction.transact(xa)
```

Note the `to[ConnectionIO]`. It takes an implicit argument of type `LiftIO` which looks like this and does pretty much what you want (lifts an `IO` into `F`):

```
trait LiftIO[F[_]] {
  def liftIO[A](ioa: IO[A]): F[A]
}
```