# Doobie - lifting arbitrary effect into ConnectionIO CE3

Tags: scala, cats-effect, doobie

I am trying to migrate project from cats-effect 2 to cats-effect 3, i am using doobie for interacting with database. Previously i could lift `ConnectionIO` to `IO` as it was [described](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61406435/13380754), but with the upgrade i didn't find any implementation of `LiftIO[ConnectionIO]`, how can be same achieved with CE3?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's two approaches here. Broadly, there's the "don't do that" option (recommended), and the other way would be to use `WeakAsync`

### "Don't do that"

Generally, it's not recommended to interleave arbitrary `IO` into a `ConnectionIO` program, because `ConnectionIO` is transactional, and you cannot roll back an `IO`. A `ConnectionIO` might run multiple times, for example to retry a recoverable failure.

When possible, it's a good idea to refactor the code to not do the non-transactional operation inside a transaction, but instead to perform it afterwards

However, when that's not practical, `ConnectionIO` provides a `Sync` instance, and so there's a number of things you can do with it easily that don't require lifting from `IO` in the first place:

- printing to the console can be done by summoning `Console[ConnectionIO]`
- Getting the current time can be done with `Clock[ConnectionIO]`
- You can create a log4cats `Logger[ConnectionIO]` as needed using the appropriate factory for your backend
- Generating a UUID value can be done with `UUIDGen[ConnectionIO]`

### Using `WeakAsync`

Doobie's `WeakAsync` provides a way to get a `Resource[F, F ~> ConnectionIO]`

Note that because this is a resource, you must take care to complete the transaction inside of `use` - the lifecycle of the `FunctionK` from the resource will be shut down once `use` completes.

Usually that means something like this:

```scala
def doStuff(rows: List[Int]): F[Unit] = ???

WeakAsync.liftK[F, ConnectionIO].use { fk =>
  val transaction = for {
    rows <- sql"select 1".query[Int].to[List]
    _ <- fk(doStuff(rows))
  } yield ()

  transaction.transact(xa)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the way to achieve it by

```
def f()(implicit liftToConnectionIO: FunctionK[IO, ConnectionIO]): IO[Unit] = IO.unit
implicit val liftToConnectionIO = WeakAsync.liftK[IO, ConnectionIO]
liftToConnectionIO.use(implicit lift => f())
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).